# Displaying result in tkinter interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use only tkinter interface to display the result, knowing I use the lists in my program. 
Here is the code :

```
NM =int(input("give the value of NM \n"))
n = int(input("give the value of n \n"))
def function(NM,n):    
    Z=[]
    for x in range(NM):
        F=float(input("give the value of F"+str(x+1)+"\n"))
        H=float(input("give the value of H"+str(x+1)+"\n"))
        v=F/H
        Z.append(v)
    s=0   
    for i in range(len(Z)):
        s+=float(Z[i])
    return (1/n)*s`
```

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format your [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show something with Tkiner maybe you can try this:

```
from tkinter import *
#creates your root widget.
root = Tk()
#creates a label so you can show your result, .path() method makes your label always stay in the center of your widget. 
Label(root, text = your_result).pack()
#allows you to see your widget.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The assignment is useless for the line `label = Label(root, text = your_result).pack()` because `label` will be `None` as it is the result of `pack()`, not `Label(...)`.